# Angular flex layout how to conditionally add fxLayoutAlign

Tags: angular6, angular-flex-layout

this is my code

```
<div fxLayout="row"
     fxLayoutAlign="end center">
```

I want to add a condition to fxLayoutAlign. i am not sure how to do this. can anyone help?

i tried the following:

```
<div fxLayout="row"
     fxLayoutAlign="isCondition? 'start center' : 'end center'">
```

but nothing is working

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is working for me.
I used the propertyBinding in square brackets.

Comment: Great! Adding the square bracket's worked for me too: `[fxLayoutAlign]="isCondition ? 'start center' : 'end center'"`